# How can i write the json schema if json has multiple data set

Tags: ruby, json, jsonschema

I am new to this json schema , i am able to write json schema if it has only one data set like below

```
{
    "employees": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "aaa"
        }
}
```

example json-schema for this is

```
{   
        "type" : "object",
            "required" : ["employees"],
            "properties" : {        
                "employees" : { "type" : "Array",
                                "items" : [
                                "properties" : {
                                                    "id" : {"type" : "integer"},
                                                    "name" : {"type" : "string"},                                                   
                                                },
                                            "required" : ["id","name"]
                                            ]
                                }
                            }
}
```

but i got stuck to write json schema in ruby if we have multiple data sets

```
{
    "employees": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "aaa"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "bbb"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "cccc"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "ddd"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "eeee"
        }
    ]
}
```

can anyone please help me to write json schema if it has multiple data sets for same schema to validate the response body

Comment: you can write hash, then convert it to json

Comment: but always count of employees data set is not same , it will increase if they insert new record in db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the schema you are looking for.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["employees"],
  "properties": {
    "employees": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": { "type": "integer" },
          "name": { "type": "string" }
        },
        "required": ["id", "name"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You were really close.  The `items` keyword has two forms.  The value of `items` can be a schema or an array of schemas(1).

If `items` is a schema, it means that every item in the array must conform to that schema.  This is the form that is useful in this case.

If the value of `items` is an array of schemas, it describes a tuple.  For example, this schema ...

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    { "type": "boolean" },
    { "type": "string" }
  ]
}
```

would validate this ...

```
[true, "foo"]
```

1. http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor37

Comment: Argghh.  You were way ahead of me.  I found getting the nesting right to be very time consuming.

Comment: @json Thank a lot dude for helping me out